# Iterating all Python list values starting at a specific index

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing, iteration

Is there a way to loop over all the values in a Python list but starting at a specific index?

For example:

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Start looping at index 1 and print out the result. My expected output would be:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

I know using two "for loops" can do the job but is there any better way to do this?

Comment: how big is the list?

Answer (score 6):

Well, you could just use the built-in [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) class, which supports ["rotating"](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate):

```
>>> from collections import deque

>>> li = deque(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> li.rotate(-1)
>>> li
deque(['b', 'c', 'd', 'a'])
```

Just in case you really want to have a list as result you can always convert it back again:

```
>>> list(li)
['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

Answer (score 3):

You could either do this with slicing:

```
l2 = [*li[1:], *li[:1]]
for i in l2:
    print(i)
```

Which works for Pythons >= `3.5`. For versions prior to that you could use `li[1:] + li[:1]` or `chain(li[1:],li[:1])` with `chain` from `itertools`.

Alternatively, using two other helpers from the `itertools` module you could do:

```
# call list on it if you need a list object
it = islice(cycle(li), 1, len(li)+1)    
for i in it:
    print(i)
```

which doesn't create the extra lists.

Comment: for i in li[1:] + li[:1]: print(i) works for any version of python and is IMO the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Though using builtin functions is the recommended way, you can still do it yourself like this.

> To answer your question about **iterating** (with simple index manipulation):

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
i_offset = 1
for i in range(len(li)):
    print (li[(i+i_offset) % len(li)])
```

> To answer your question about **printing a list** (in a more pythonic way):

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
i_offset = 1
print ([li[(i+i_offset) % len(li)] for i,x in enumerate(li)])
```

No need to convert to queues and convert back to lists to achieve it.

Comment: You're right that `deque` isn't necessary to solve the problem - but it's built-in (so everyone has access to it) and it nativly supports rotation. So even though it's not necessary using it makes the code easier and (probably) faster. Note that converting it back is completly optional (if that wasn't obvious I can make it clearer in my answer), the `deque` itself is just like a list when it comes to iteration. I'm also glad you edited your answer, now it actually solves the problem. :)

Comment: Also note that the question is tagged python-3.x so you probably should add parenthesis (`()`) to the `print`s.

Comment: Thanks @MSeifert for your inputs, I edited my answer. Your answer is interesting indeed, so it shows a nice Python feature and that's good approach to use built-in functions when they make it easier. I do not think it be faster since Python doc mentions `deque` appends all elements into new object. You're right about my 1st answer, I should not do that so late at night :)

Comment: I know that `deque` is faster. I timed it before I commented on your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own generator function `looper` and then loop through the generator returned by it. The generator function takes the list as first argument and the desired starting-index as second input. The modulo-operator (`%`) does the trick to keep the index within the bounds of the list.

```
def looper(my_list, starting_ix):
    len_ml = len(my_list)
    for i in range(starting_ix, len_ml + starting_ix):
        yield my_list[i % len_ml]

li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for item in looper(li, 1):
    print item
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

append list after list, and iterate `start_index` to `start_index+len(list)`.

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5]
start_idx = 3
for num in (ary+ary)[start_idx:start_idx+len(ary)]:
    print(num)
```

Comment: you forgot the closing `]` after the `start_idx+len(ary)`. Also "append list after list" is also called "concatenation" (just meant as clarification - I guess everyone knows what you meant). :)

Comment: I' fix my answer typo. 
I'm not good at English, I hope you understand.

Comment: You inserted it at the wrong place: It should be `[start_idx:start_idx+len(ary)]` (note the different order of the last two characters). :)

Comment: I'm so sorry... I'm so dizzy cause final test. ㅠㅠ

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the update. Normally I would do the edit myself but it felt wrong to edit your post just to add one character. :)